# Test class for http callout doesn't work because a value within the controller method it's not populated as it should in the test method

Tags: unit-test, httpcalloutmock

I have this apex controller which has a method that does a POST request to captcha api. From lwc component I receive a token which I use in my method.

**controller class**

```
public with sharing class ShipperCaptchaController {

    public static final String verifyUrl = 'https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify';

    @AuraEnabled (cacheable = true)
    public static String getSiteKey() {
        Digital_Platform__c digitalPlatform = Digital_Platform__c.getOrgDefaults();
        String siteKey = digitalPlatform.Captcha_Key__c;
        return siteKey;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean sendRequestToCaptcha(String token) {
        Digital_Platform__c digitalPlatform = Digital_Platform__c.getOrgDefaults();
        String secret = digitalPlatform.Captcha_Secret__c;
       
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(verifyUrl);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Length', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        String payload = 'response=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(token,'UTF-8') + '&secret=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(secret,'UTF-8');
        request.setBody(payload);

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        Boolean isCaptchaValid;

        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
           Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            Boolean result = (Boolean) responseMap.get('success');

            if(result) {
                isCaptchaValid = true;
            } else {
                isCaptchaValid = false;
            }
        } 
        return isCaptchaValid;
    }
}
```

The issue is in the test class because it's failing with error message "Argument cannot be null". It's referring to this line from the controller -> String payload = 'response=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(token,'UTF-8') + '&secret=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(secret,'UTF-8'); The problem is that secret variable it's null and I don't understand why because in the sendRequestToCaptcha method it's populated.

**test class**

```
@isTest
public class ShipperCaptchaControllerTest {

    @isTest
    public static void testSendRequestToCaptcha() {
        
        // Create mock HTTP callout
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new DP_MockServices.ShipperCaptchaMock(200));
       
        // Call the method under test
        Test.startTest();
        Boolean result = ShipperCaptchaController.sendRequestToCaptcha('mockToken');
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Assert the expected result
        System.assertEquals(true, result);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Is `Digital_Platform__c` a hierarchy-type custom setting? If so, then you need to create and insert a test record for it in your test method because custom settings are _data_ rather than _metadata_.